# Scaling Wordpress images to same height inside Bootstrap flex-row flex-nowrap

Tags: css, wordpress, image, bootstrap-5, image-scaling

I have Bootstrap integrated with Wordpress Underscores Template.

I want to make a horizontaly scrollable container with images that have the same height.

I'm stuck on the point, that I have scrollable container, but images height is not the same;

```css
/*for example purposes*/
.example{
  background:pink;
}

/*underscores style.css*/
img {
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid overflow-auto border border-dark">
        <div class="row flex-row flex-nowrap">
            <div class="col-3"><img class="example" width="755" height="523"><br><em>text1</em></div> 
            <div class="col-3"><img class="example" width="555" height="623"><br><em>text2</em></div> 
            <div class="col-3"><img class="example" width="455" height="123"><br><em>text3</em></div> 
            <div class="col-3"><img class="example" width="255" height="323"><br><em>text4</em></div> 
            <div class="col-3"><img class="example" width="555" height="823"><br><em>text5</em></div> 
        </div>
    </div
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to match the size of images and you don't know the specific size of each of them, it is best to make them fit using css.

The **object-fit** property is great. It helps us resize an  or  to fit its container. It works just like a background-image.

It has different properties that will be useful depending on what you want to do. It is important to define the size of the container so that it fits correctly.

[Here more information about this property](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

The interesting thing is that it has a property to align the position of the element inside the container, this is called [object-position](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/object-position)

Check this in your style.
Define a height for the images, the rest is done.

```
img {
    height: 250px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

Comment: `object-fit: cover;` solves the problem, although would be nice, if you provide more detailed answer for future readers